# Charset in XML output from SQL .. german characters .. where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, character-encoding

Thanks for taking the time!

I am trying to put together a mapping app to experiment with the Google Maps V3 API.  It is also my first time outputting XML with PHP/SQL and then processing the results.

I am using this as my guide >> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html

My problem is when I use a SQL table containing German addresses/characters, it doesn't work -- I get this error thrown to me

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
```

..and examining the page source I see this...

```
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMElement::setAttribute() [<a href='domelement.setattribute'>domelement.setattribute</a>]: string is not in UTF-8 in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/guruTest/guruTest.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::saveXML() [<a  href='domdocument.savexml'>domdocument.savexml</a>]: output conversion failed due to conv  error, bytes 0xDF 0x65 0x20 0x33 in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/guruTest/guruTest.php</b>  on line <b>52</b><br />
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<markers>
```

Using the same PHP/SQL but switching to a database of English addresses, it works fine.  So it seems the problem is the German characters in my German addresses.

I had originally started with the code pretty much as you see on code.google.com.  In that example, no charset is given for the XML document.

Here is where I think the problem is

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
```

When I started seeing the errors with my German info I added encoding to the head declaration. Simply by doing this...

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset: UTF-8");
```

But my error-ridden XML output was still showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

.. so .. I clearly have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.

Anyone want to help out?

Comment: I wonder if has to do with you database query (i.e. try SELECT ... COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)... just guessing :)

Comment: what are you using to build the xml?  what is $dom

Comment: Just wanted to say that I got around the problem by HTML encoding my database info and reimporting it into my table.  Since it was only a test situation with few entries this was not difficult.  

Is this normal behaviour to encode HTML entities before entering data into a database?  Anybody?

Answer (score 4):

Use this string function while you pass the variable:

```
utf8_encode($variable);
```